# How to let Webpack require a root node_module instead of an child package?

Tags: backbone.js, npm, webpack

I have installed backbone and backbone.babysitter trough npm. When I use backbone in my scripts like this: `import Backbone from "backbone";` It loads the installed backbone version `1.2.1`. This works fine until I want to use backbone.babysitter. When backbone.babysitter loads it needs to add properties to backbone itself. But the package of backbone.babysitter imports its own backbone as dependency in his own node_modules folder, this backbone is on `1.2.0`. So it attaches his methods to a different backbone i am working with.

How can I force Webpack to require the backbone from the root `node_modules` folder for backbone.babysitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a [workaround here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/777#issuecomment-73615754)

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'backbone': require.resolve('backbone')
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`NormalModuleReplacementPlugin`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#normalmodulereplacementplugin) to rewire all `require('backbone')` towards your root backbone module.

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/^backbone$/, require.resolve('backbone')),
],
```